# is there a way to open a file in webpack browser extension application

Tags: npm, webpack, google-chrome-extension, fs

When compiling my browser extension project I have this error :

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\admin\project\node_modules\pdf-table-extractor'
```

I'm using **webpack** and **npm**. 
**pdf-table-extractor** is an **npm** library that extracts pdf data in Json format.
This library require the **fs** library to open the pdf file path.

It seems that this library is somehow blocked by **webpack**.

Can any one help with this ?

Adding
 node: {
        fs: 'empty'
    }
to the **"webpack.config.js"** file solve the compiling error but the extension  is failing in the browser.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Extensions run in the browser environment and browsers can't run `fs` package.

Comment: Is there any work around for this ?

Comment: Generally, no. You need to investigate how it's used and see if it can be replaced/removed.